# VK API как вывести на сайте товары из сообщества

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Я запутался с ключами и вообще потерял мысль подскажите как правильно и проще вывести на страницу товары из сообщества в vk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшим рецептом вывода товаров на сайте будет выгрузка их не через JavaScript, а на языке, на котором написан ваш сайт. Например, на PHP.

1. Создайте приложение типа "standalone" на [странице создания приложений](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create).
2. Откройте в браузере ссылку `https://api.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456789&scope=market,offline&response_type=token&v=5.59`, заменив `123456789` на ID вашего приложения (можно узнать во вкладке "Настройки" приложения). Если вы захотите дать приложению больше прав, например, чтобы делать обращения не только к методам товаров, но и другим, вам надо будет в параметре `scope` указать больше прав. Смотрите больше о правах вот [тут](https://vk.com/dev/permissions).
3. После того, как вы разрешите вашему приложению доступ к своему аккаунту, адресная строка браузера изменится: `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=ea05c261301bfsdf416d9145ac1ee95f438cb2c87bb9212335f3ebed3eqwe7e8a458c3164567123aca59e1de&expires_in=0&user_id=1234567`. В данном примере ваш токен - это `ea05c261301bfsdf416d9145ac1ee95f438cb2c87bb9212335f3ebed3eqwe7e8a458c3164567123aca59e1de`.

Теперь у вас есть access_token, также известный как ключ доступа пользователя, с которым вы можете делать запросы к API. Например, вот так: `https://api.vk.com/method/market.get?owner_id=-124527492&access_token=ea05c261301bfsdf416d9145ac1ee95f438cb2c87bb9212335f3ebed3eqwe7e8a458c3164567123aca59e1de&v=5.59`

Comment: Спасибо! все разложили по полочкам

Answer (score 2):

Раз вы указали в вопросе тег javascript, предположу, что вы пользуетесь [Open API](https://vk.com/dev/openapi) или [JavaScript SDK](https://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK). Примеры будут написаны на Open API, но если вы работаете с JavaScript SDK, то замените в примере ниже метод `VK.Api.call` на `VK.api`.

```
VK.Api.call('market.get', {'owner_id': -124527492}, function(data) {
  if (typeof data['error'] !== 'undefined') {
    alert('Произошла ошибка VK API #' + data['error']['error_code'] + ': ' + data['error']['error_msg']);

    return;
  }

  data['response']['items'].forEach(function(item) {
    $('body').append('<p>' + item['title'] + ' (' + item['price']['text'] + ')</p>');
    $('body').append('<img src="' + item['thumb_photo'] + '" alt="' + item['title'] + '">');
    $('body').append('<hr>');
  });
});
```

JavaScript SDK используется в iFrame-приложениях (в т.ч. в "приложениях сообществ"), а Open API - на обычных сайтах. Обратите внимание на то, что метод [market.get](https://vk.com/dev/market.get) не работает без авторизации пользователя, поэтому в случае с iFrame-приложением вам надо будет запрашивать у пользователя доступ к товарам, а в случае с Open API - делать [авторизацию на сайте](https://vk.com/dev/openapi?f=3.%20%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) и также запрашивать доступ к товарам.

Но правильнее всего было бы сделать выгрузку товаров не через JavaScript, а на языке, на котором написан ваш сайт. Например, на PHP.

Comment: А без авторизации ? Есть варианты? Допустим товары на стену и получать со стены? Или сделать приложение?

Comment: Без авторизации ваших пользователей самым правильным вариантом будет делать выгрузку товаров на сервере, например, на PHP. Данный подход избавит вас от создания велосипедов и по удобству для пользователей он будет самым лучшим и прозрачным. В комментарии всё не уместится, поэтому я сейчас напишу отдельный ответ к вашему вопросу.