# VK API Передать полученный токен доступа в заголовок http-запроса

Tags: vkontakte-api, http, httpclient

Нужно отправить токен доступа в заголовк http-запроса.
Вк не видит токен, должна быть другая ошибка, что токен не валидный.

```
{
  "error": {
    "error_code": 5,
    "error_msg": "User authorization failed: no access_token passed.",
    "request_params:" [
      {
        "key": "oauth",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "market.get"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Посмотри похожий вопрос здесь [VK API как вывести на сайте товары из сообщества](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584427/vk-api-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Comment: @AndrewTymchenko Как получать токен и пользоваться методами - я знаю. Не возникает проблем, когда пользуюсь get-запросом, передавая access_token через get параметр. Проблема заключается в передаче токена **именно** через http-заголовок. вопрос состоит в том, как это сделать...

Comment: А зачем так делать-то? Не думаю, что у ВК это реализовано, ибо зачем?

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно отправить токен доступа в заголовк http-запроса

У VK API нет такого функционала. В GET-запросах токен можно передавать только как GET-параметр (в query string), а в POST-запросах только в теле запроса. В обоих случаях имя параметра одинаковое: `access_token`.

Answer (score 0):

Делаю запрос по API c OAuth2 токеном с разными провайдерами. Результаты такие:

- Yandex - только Authorization хедер "OAuth *token*"
- GitHub - Authorization хедер: "token *token*" , параметр access_token - depricated
- Google - Authorization хедер: "Bearer *token*" или параметр access_token
- FaceBook - Authorization хедер: "Bearer или OAuth *token*" или параметр access_token
- VK - похоже что только параметр access_token ....